# Compile C file for using in android

Tags: android, c, makefile, cmake, android-ndk

I want to compile following repo for using it in android and use `tun2socks` file in android phone
https://github.com/shadowsocks/badvpn

I executed the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_NOTHING_BY_DEFAULT=1 -DBUILD_TUN2SOCKS=1
make install
```

But I got the following errors:

```
/home/mohsen/badvpn/tun2socks/tun2socks.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/mohsen/badvpn/tun2socks/tun2socks.c:488:16: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘fake_proc’
     if (options.fake_proc) {
```

There is a macro `__ANDROID__` in source files

How can I set this variable to 1 so the project compile for android device?

How can I compile it for using output binary in `arm` and `x86` android processor?

Comment: "How can I set this variable to 1 so the project compile for android device?" - You need to specify appropriate toolchain. Just google how to build CMake projects for Android. See e.g. here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake